# Why do polynomial solutions of the differential equation $y^{(4)} -4y^{(2)}=x^2+e^x$ have to be of 4th degree?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials

$$y^{(4)} -4y^{(2)}=x^2+e^x$$ Why does the solution for the polynomial part(of the particular solution) need to be of order 4: $AX^4+BX^3+CX^2+DX+E$ (it is how WolframAlpha seems to solve it) isn't the order supposed to be 2- according to the LHS of the equation?

Comment: Which polynomial? Are you expecting the [solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=D%5By%2C+%7Bx%2C4%7D%5D+-+4*D%5By%2C+%7Bx%2C+2%7D%5D+%3D+x%5E2+%2B+e%5Ex) $y$ to be a polynomial?
(this is not possible over the reals, because of the $e^x$ term; just plug *any* polynomial and look at the limit at $+\infty$)

Comment: if $y$ is a quadratic polynomial in $x$ then the left-hand side of the equation is a constant

Comment: the polynomial part of the particular solution is of order 4 by the final answer...may you please show how to solve the part  of the particular solution?

Comment: @ Amzoti Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a RHS of the form

$$
b(x)=e^{\alpha x}\left(P_m(x)\cos\beta x+Q_n(x)\sin\beta x\right)
$$

a particular solutions is given by

$$
y_p(x)=x^r e^{\alpha x}\left(R_k(x)\cos\beta x+S_k(x)\sin\beta x\right)
$$

where $r$ is the multiplicity of $\alpha+i\beta$ as a root of the characteristic polynomial (zero if it is not a root).

In your case $\alpha=\beta=0$, and $0$ is a double root of the characteristic polynomial, so the particular solution reduces to

$$
y_p(x)=x^2 R_k(x)
$$

where $R_k$ is a polynomial of degree $2$.